# Is it possible to use json key instead of p12 key for service account credentials?

Tags: c#, google-bigquery, google-sheets-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using "Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2 Client Library" with C#.

I am authorizing to Google BigQuery using "Service Account" (see http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/OAuth2GoogleServiceAccounts.html). To create the X509 certificate I use the p12 key from the Google Developers Console. However, right now the json key is the default. Can I use it instead the p12 key?

I have the following code:

```
    string serviceAccountEmail = "xxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

X509Certificate2 certificate;
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\key.p12", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
        certificate = new X509Certificate2(ms.ToArray(), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    }
}

// Create credentials
ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] {
        BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery,
        BigqueryService.Scope.CloudPlatform,
    },
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// Create the service
BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "My Application",
    GZipEnabled = true,
};

BigqueryService service = new BigqueryService(initializer);
var projects = service.Projects.List().Execute();
```

Comment: Similar (unanswered) question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884184

Comment: Have you tried using this flow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977864/nativeapplicationclient-is-not-supported-any but for BQ?

Comment: This is actually very close. Do you have a similar example for ServiceAccountCredential (not UserCredential)?

Comment: Looking at the source code I don't think its possible. Reading the example project they use ServiceAccountCredentials for all except with Json. https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/9405c89aff6cc7454619a5af560f3b7efbc3f4f6/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/ServiceAccountCredential.cs https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-dotnet-samples

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is now possible (I used v 1.13.1.0 of Google APIs).

Example for BigQuery:

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\mykey.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
}

string[] scopes = new string[] {
    BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery,
    BigqueryService.Scope.CloudPlatform, 
};
credential = credential.CreateScoped(scopes);

BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = (IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer)credential,
    ApplicationName = "My Application",
    GZipEnabled = true,
};
BigqueryService service = new BigqueryService(initializer);
```

Example for Google Sheets:

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"mykey.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
}
credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[] { 
    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", 
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds" });

string bearer;
try
{
    Task<string> task = ((ITokenAccess)credential).GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
    task.Wait();
    bearer = task.Result;
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    throw ex.InnerException;
}

GDataRequestFactory requestFactory = new GDataRequestFactory("My Application");
requestFactory.CustomHeaders.Add(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Authorization: Bearer {0}", bearer));

SpreadsheetsService service = new SpreadsheetsService("My Application");
service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the link, Which indicates **Service Account Authentication using JSON file in C# application is not yet added in Google BigQuery API**.

https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/533

Comment: Please note, "Not yet" is in the past. Currently writing August 2019, both approaches are working well.

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me:

```
var scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive };

ServiceAccountCredential credential;
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\path\key.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    credential =
        GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes).UnderlyingCredential as
            ServiceAccountCredential;
}
```

Obviously, you would provide your own values for the `scopes` variable and for the path to the key file. You would also need to get the `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2` Nuget package plus whatever other service-specific package you plan on using the credential with (in my case it is `Google.Apis.Drive.v3`).

Comment: I wonder why this is so simpler compared to the other examples above. Going to try it out.