# Invalid JWT when trying to connect to Google Oauth for google API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, jwt

I was trying to connect to Google API through OAuth through JWT, but I keep getting this error:

> { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe" }

In my JWT calim I set the iat to be current time minus 1970-01-01 in seconds and exp to iat + 3600, so I do not know why I am still getting this error. If anyone knows the answer please tell meeeeee!

Comment: Are you making your own JWT claim?  time needs to be the current time NTP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol

Comment: thanks for the reply, I set the time to UTC and now I'm getting a invalid signature error, would you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: $sig = hash_hmac('sha256', utf8_encode($base64encodedHeaderAndPayload), "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n privatekey \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n");
  



$signature = base64url_encode($sig);

Comment: Note a clue I have also tried to create my own JWT token ever managed to get it to work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33438494/google-service-account-authentication-with-json-file   I use have been stuck using Googles client library's.  What language are you using maybe you can pick apart the client library code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you ever got it to work, but the following simple steps worked for me using the PHP function [openssl_sign()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php):

```php
//helper function
function base64url_encode($data) { 
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
}

//Google's Documentation of Creating a JWT: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

//{Base64url encoded JSON header}
$jwtHeader = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
    "alg" => "RS256",
    "typ" => "JWT"
)));
//{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}
$now = time();
$jwtClaim = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
    "iss" => "761326798069-r5mljlln1rd4lrbhg75efgigp36m78j5@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
    "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
    "aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    "exp" => $now + 3600,
    "iat" => $now
)));
//The base string for the signature: {Base64url encoded JSON header}.{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}
openssl_sign(
    $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim,
    $jwtSig,
    $your_private_key_from_google_api_console,
    "sha256WithRSAEncryption"
);
$jwtSign = base64url_encode($jwtSig);

//{Base64url encoded JSON header}.{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}.{Base64url encoded signature}
$jwtAssertion = $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim.".".$jwtSig;
```

Comment: Sorry I kept forgetting to update this. This was indeed the right answer! Although I don't need to use this anymore because App Engine allows me to directly reach Cloud Storage now. But still thank you for the right answer! :)

Comment: Hey @Joseph Shih I am having similar issue, my error is `Invalid JWT Signature.`. Can you share your POST request. I guess I'm having issues with `grant_type` in the request body.

Comment: @Michel, an invalid JWT signature error means that your signature failed to authenticate your $jwtHeader and $jwtClaim. Are you using the correct ISS (email address of the service account) and are you using the private key from your API console. Also, remember you'll need to base-64 encode the signature (like the example above).

Comment: Never mind @JosephShih I was able to fix it. I posted the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48106432/invalid-signature-google-jwt-api      Still thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I solved it by syncing my VMs time to have the correct one with a public ntpserver:

```
ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a correct expiration time for the token if you see this error. Example:

```
var currentTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000; //must be in seconds
var exp = currentTime + 60;

var auth_claimset = {
      iss       :   "...",
      scope     :   "...",
      aud       :   "...",
      exp       :   exp,
      iat       :   currentTime 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the steps under HTTP/Rest here: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#formingheader, you'll see that your service accounts support RSA SHA-256, and you appear to use HMAC.

Comment: So I have modified to the below code:
'
    $sig = hash('SHA256', $headerAndPayload, $secret);
    $signature = base64url_encode($sig);
    $jwt = $headerAndPayload . "." . $signature;
'
I keep getting a signature invalid for some reason. $secret is the private key i obtained from service account key json file. Would you know what's wrong?

Comment: I just found out that using hash in PHP does not use a secret key, so I should probably still use hash_hmac, and I am not getting a result :/

Comment: There appear to be signing libraries that create spec compliant JWTs. For example: https://github.com/namshi/jose

Answer (score 0):

This happens with WSL as well if you are doing testing on a local dev machine with WSL2 backend on Docker in Windows it will cause this problem.

You need to install ntpdate

```
sudo apt install ntpdate
```

Then you need to set the time.

```
sudo ntpdate time.windows.com
```

Good article about it here - https://tomssl.com/fixing-clock-drift-in-wsl2-using-windows-terminal/