# Google Analytics API v4 Symfony bundle

Tags: google-analytics-api, symfony-2.8

Im using Google Analytics API v4 Symfony bundle  to get reporting .. 
 i following this tuto https://github.com/mediafigaro/google-analytics-api-symfony
but i found this error:

> {
>   "error": "invalid_grant",
>   "error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
>   }[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khDrA.png)

Comment: For people who are still finding for an answer, it is probably a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909121/invalid-jwt-when-trying-to-connect-to-google-oauth-for-google-api