# Invalid Signature - Google JWT API

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, google-api, jwt

I'm trying to sign a request for Google 0Auth2 (in PHP)
Here's my code:

```
$jwtHeader = $this->base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
                "alg" => "RS256",
                "typ" => "JWT"
                )));
$now = time();
            $jwtClaim = $this->base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
                "iss" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx.gserviceaccount.com",
                "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
                "aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                "iat" => $now, 
                "exp" => $now + 3600,
                )));

$sign = hash_hmac('SHA256', $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim, $secret);
$jwtAssertion = $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim.".".$sign;

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', ['headers' => ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'], 'form_params' => ['grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer', 'assertion' => $jwtAssertion]]);
if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
    return $res->getBody()->getContents();
}

//BASE64 METHOD
public function base64url_encode($data) { 
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
}
```

The response I get is

```
{
"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "Invalid JWT Signature."
}
```

Been on this for some hours now, still getting same error. Anyone come across this? 
I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Its hard to tell whats wrong RS256 is for asymmetric, do you have the public key setup etc? Are you sure `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` is whats expected? Can you also show base64url_encode method, other then that the code looks fine.

Comment: Bingo, your not base64ing the hmac signature

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks for the reply. I have the private key gotten from the downloaded json file after setting the service account, which is my `$secret` here. `urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` yes that's what the doc says. base64url_encode method is just a base64_encode with no padding. I will update the question to include that method

Comment: I also did encode the signature to base64. Still got same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay for the sake of those that might encounter the same issue. This how I solved it:

```
            $jwtHeader = $this->base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
                "alg" => "RS256",
                "typ" => "JWT"
                )));
            $now = time();
            $jwtClaim = $this->base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
                "iss" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxx.gserviceaccount.com",
                "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/prediction",
                "aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
                "iat" => $now, 
                "exp" => $now + 3600,
                )));
            $secret = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";

            $binary_signature = "";
            $algo = "SHA256";
            openssl_sign($jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim, $binary_signature, $secret, $algo);
            $jwtSign = $this->base64url_encode($binary_signature);
            $jwtAssertion = $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim.".".$jwtSign;

            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $res = $client->post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', ['headers' => ['Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'], 'form_params' => ['grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer', 'assertion' => $jwtAssertion]]);
            if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
                return $res->getBody()->getContents();
            }

        public function base64url_encode($data) { 
            return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
        }
```

This works as expected.