# Is it possible to use json key instead of p12 key for service account credentials for google calendar API in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have gone through [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840686/is-it-possible-to-use-json-key-instead-of-p12-key-for-service-account-credential) but the links on this page is not opening.
I want to use to use Json key instead of p12 key for service account credentials.
I didn't found step by step code for json.
How to do that?. Any links will also be helpfull.

[image: JSON]

Comment: Please see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840686/is-it-possible-to-use-json-key-instead-of-p12-key-for-service-account-credential.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible to use JSON file for service account credentials.

You must obtain these credentials in the Google Developers Console. To generate service-account credentials do the following:

- Open the Google Developer Console (Credentials page)
- To set up a new service account, do the following:
  a. Click Add credentials > Service account.
  b. Choose whether P12 file or JSON file.

Your new public/private key pair is generated and downloaded to your machine; it serves as the only copy of this key. You are responsible for storing it securely.

Comment: I have already gone through this steps but want the code to use i in C# language to get information from Google calendar API

Comment: Have you tried this tutorial? http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/

Comment: yes but that code is for P12 and not JSON. I have added an image in main section so that you will get proper idea.